# streamlit markdown color change not working

Tags: python, streamlit

My streamlit markdown text is all coming white and I want it to be black. Here is what my markdown code is but it just inputs everything as it is:

```
st.markdown(
        """
        <span style='color:black'>This is First page
        You can:
        - Say Hi
        - Send email
        - Contact via form </span>
    """
    )
```

I also tried to use `:black[]` under markdown text and it was still same
My streamlit version is `1.21.0`

**Note**: I do have a background image on my frame

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `unsafe_allow_html` to True in your function.
[Here's the related documentation](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/text/st.markdown)

```py
st.markdown(
        """
        <span style='color:black'>This is First page
        You can:
        - Say Hi
        - Send email
        - Contact via form </span>
    """,
    unsafe_allow_html=True
    )
```

Please note that you need to wrap each item of the list with span to have everything black.